# Persisting data with js for a small web project without a database

Tags: javascript, html

I recently started developing my first (rather crappy) webpage. It is for my commune that just displays who has to clean the kitchen on a given day and a picture of him. Now I would also like to make a little rating system, where you can give a rating between 1 and 5 starts. Is there any way to persist the rating without using a database? Could I, for example, just save it to a textfile that i read to and write from?

edit:

The website is hosted on an apache server

Comment: Yes, the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) . This isn't a particularly great question for SO, probably better for the Software Design SE

Comment: @user1538301, The Web Storage API only stores data in the browser. How do you suggest the user's rating is to be stored *on the website* using a client-side feature? krise, You can definitely use a text file to store the data instead of a database. What are you using for a web server though? (node.js, Apache, IIS, etc.) We need to know this to be able to help you.

Comment: Web Storage can be deleted easily. You should use a database, or create a JSON file you can force a download on to reinput the data in case your Browser deletes `localStorage`, or save a JSON page to the Server.

Comment: @StackSlave he explicitly said a database is not an option.

Comment: @user1538301, I don't think there is much to discuss. We both have different ideas about how to fill in the information gaps in this question. Obviously we need to give OP a chance to update with more info or the question should be closed. My first comment was not just addressing your Web Storage suggestion, but also requesting information that will allow us to answer the question. I can delete some comments if you'd like to clean up this thread...

Comment: I use a friends webserver, as I said, my first webpage, I dont really understand much of frontend stuff, I just send him my html file, he hosts it. He has an apachi server

Comment: @krise, Thanks for the update. Do you want the ratings to be stored on the server for all users to see? (To compute an average rating?). Or are the ratings for each user's personal record and therefore do not need to be saved on the server?

Comment: Op, you could but I don't see how that would be easier. Database exists for a reason.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a database? There are many small, free, easy-to-learn, open-source databases out there that you could probably implement in an afternoon. If you use a text file, you have to do the work the database does for you, like organizing what goes where, looking things up, updating values, etc.. Anyway, an idea.

Comment: I want to store the average rating on the server to display it to users. As to why I don't want to use a database: Its just a little sideproject and I dont want to spend an afternoon setting up the database. For my current purposes (saving avg rating) a text file would be much easier

Comment: @krise, I suggest that you look into PHP and learn how to convert the code for your webpage to a PHP script. That way you would be able to execute code on the server and save/load a text file containing the ratings. Handling the submission of the ratings is also a server-side task, that can't be implemented in just HTML & JS at all!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

To store anything on the server, you're going to need to learn a server-side language, like PHP, C#, or Java. Any server framework will already have stuff built in for working with a database, so if you go and reinvent your own, you'll just be creating more work for yourself. If I were you, I'd start with some simple tutorials for your server language of choice.

Also consider that even a simple rating system isn't as trivial as you might think. Some things you may want:

- Authentication: should everyone in the world be able to access your site?
- Permissions: can anyone update any rating?